# Problems referencing a series of controls on a header in a form in Access using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

In Access form designer I have created 73 Labels, named Label0 to Label72.  The labels are in the form header of the form "MainScreen" and the snipped is called on upon the form opening.

I am trying to update their positions using this snippet, but it's not working, any idea why not or how to make it work?

I get the error "The expression you entered refers to an object that does not exist"

```
For X = 0 To 72
   CtName = "Label" + Chr(X)
   If ((X Mod 2) = 0) Then
      Form_MainScreen.FormHeader.Controls(CtName).Top = 0
   Else
      Form_MainScreen.FormHeader.Controls(CtName).Top = 226
   End If
Next
```

Thanks :)

Comment: I would guess that *"The expression you entered refers to an object that does not exist"*. Can you set a breakpoint in your code and inspect the `Form_MainScreen.FormHeader.Controls` collection to confirm that the control is actually there?

Comment: Hovering the mouse over gives the same error, and so does just hovering over "Form_MainScreen.FormHeader", but I know it has a header. :/

Comment: @Tim: Hm… What do you mean by "hovering the mouse"? Just set a breakpoint on the `If … Then` line and add `Form_MainScreen.FormHeader.Controls` to the Watch window in order to inspect it when execution breaks there.

Comment: I've taken out the "FormHeader." so I just have "Form_MainScreen.Controls()" but now get the error "Can't find the field 'Label' referred to in your expression."

Comment: By hover the house over I meant see what was currently as that value at that time (gives me the same value as in a watch window)

Comment: @Tim: Ahh, I see it now, see my answer. Well, at least there is one easy-to-overlook error in your code, no idea if that is the entire problem. ;-)

Comment: I question why you think you need to do this. It's not that I've never done it, but the circumstances in which it's the way to do things are vanishingly rare, in my experience (I've done it only once).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with this assignment statement:

```
CtName = "Label" + Chr(X)
```

The *Chr(value)* function returns the character whose ASCII code matches the value you pass to it.  For example, when x=70, the value of CtName would be "LabelF" ... which is not what you want.

Use the *CStr()* function to convert a number to its string representation:

```
CtName = "Label" & CStr(x)
```

But you don't really even need the *CStr()* function; VBA will transform the number when performing concatenation (with the & operator):

```
CtName = "Label" & x
```

Finally, if your code snippet was from the form's Form_Open event, use *Me* to refer to the current form:

```
'Form_MainScreen.Controls(CtName).Top = 226 '
Me.Controls(CtName).Top = 226
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
CtName = "Label" & X
```

String concatenation does <strike>not</strike> work with `+` in VBA. *(Well it does, but only if both operands are strings. IMHO, it's better to forget that and always use `&`. See below.)*

Also, `Chr()` does not convert a number to a string, `CStr()` does that. But it's unnecessary to call it explicitly, as VBA will do the necessary conversions on its own.

---

**Correction**: To be completely honest, string concatenation in fact *does* work with `+`, see comments below. But I would definitely not recommend it, because it is error-prone when one of the operands is not a string. In my experience, it's *always* better to use `&` to concatenate strings.

Comment: @HansUp: But in this case, `X` is a number. And `"a" + 9` returns a type mismatch, whereas `"a" & 9` returns `"a9"`. String concatenation with `+` is simply a mis-use of the `+` operator, since there is a dedicated and error-proof concatenation operator available.

Comment: @Tomalak The + operator can be used to concatenate two strings.  So this statement is false and misleading: "String concatenation does not work with + in VBA".

Comment: @Tomalak String concatenation with the + operator can be useful as in: `lname & ", " & fname & (" " + middle_initial)`  In the case where middle_initial is Null, the expression returns a string without a trailing space.

Comment: @HansUp: Hm, interesting. Never thought about it that way, let alone used it that way. I'd call that rather obscure and use `lname & ", " & fname & Trim(" " & middle_initial)` or even `Trim(lname & ", " & fname & " " & middle_initial)`, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: @Tomalak I never considered using Trim() for that situation, but it seems obvious (now that you pointed it out).  Thanks.  However, I'll still hold on to the + Null approach for situations like joining an optional title (e.g. MD) to a name string with a comma.

Comment: @HansUp: Yeah. Well, there's nothing intrinsically *wrong* with that, I occasionally do the same thing in T-SQL, where I know that concatenate-null-yields-null is the default. Nevertheless this has a smell for me (even when I do it in SQL!) because it is relying on a type-conversion side-effect instead of being explicit — and I give "explicit is better than implicit" a lot of weight.

Comment: @Tomalak "explicit is better than implicit"  Are you a Python person?  I can sure get on board with that concept, but "add anything to Null yields Null" seems pretty darn explicit to me.  :-)

Comment: @HansUp: Re: Python person: In theory - yes. Python is pretty beautiful IMO. In practice - no. I don't do a lot of Python, regrettably. Maybe it's just that I was not aware that VBA works the same way when it comes to concatenating Null to a string, and I did a lot of VBA in my life. ;-) It's one of the things you have to *know*, or you will run into problems like Type Mismatch errors. Whereas a `Trim()` is pretty darn obvious. :-)

Comment: @Tomalak Me 2 -> luv Python but don't get to use it much anymore.  Regarding + and Null (or any math operation with Null), although it may be less obvious than Trim(), it's such a fundamental ubiquitous concept that, if one doesn't already know, one best learn it ASAP!  (IMO)  Cheers.

Comment: The + concatenation operator propagates Nulls. I take advantage of this all the time, for instance, to get a LastName, FirstName display: Mid(("12"+LastName) & (", "+FirstName), 3). The only danger is if any of the string values on both sides of the + are coercable to numeric values, as they will sometimes end up being added. But that doesn't happen in the places where I use Null propagation like that.